# Different generators of (x,y) in k[x,y] give rise to automorphism.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am stuck with the following algebra problem:

Let $f,g\in k[x,y]$ be polynomials which generate $(x,y)$ (as an ideal). Consider the homomorphism $\phi:k[x,y]\to k[x,y]$ which is identity on $k$, and sends $x$ to $f$, $y$ to $g$. Is $\phi$ necessarily an automorphism of $k[x,y]$? (In my case $k=\mathbb{C}$, but I think it doesn't really matter)

It is of course sufficent to prove that it is surjective (then, if it had nontrivial kernel, after taking quotient we would get a one (or zero) - dimensional ring isomorphic with $k[x,y]$, contradiction). My idea was to check it locally: in $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ it *seems* to be true (although I can't prove it), but it *seems* not to see what's going on over the other maximal ideals (although I can't find a counterexample either).

I know that it might be a silly question, but I would be really grateful for any help.

EDIT: Simone provided below a simple counterexample. However, I think it is still interesting if we assumed additionaly that these polynomials $f,g$ are both irreducible. Is the answer still negative?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I do not see the difficulty... the image of $\phi$ is a subring of $k[x,y]$ that contains $x$ and $y$... what can it be?

Comment: @Simone, $f$ and $g$ generate $(x,y)$ as an **ideal** of $k[x,y]$.

Comment: The **ideal** generated by $f$ and $g$ is the set of all linear combination $af+bg$ with $a$ and $b$ arbitrary elements of $k[x,y]$, while the **subring** generated by $f$ and $g$ (which is also the image of the map $\phi$) is the set of all polynomials of the form $F(f, g)$ with $F\in k[x,y]$: two different things... If they coincide, that fact evidently requires a proof.

Comment: Exactly - I meant "generate $(x,y)$ _as an ideal_" - I've just edited my question making it more precise.

Comment: I see... for example it seems that $(y(x+1),x)=(x,y)$ but $y\notin k[x,y(x+1)]$.

Comment: Thank you, Simone. It was the example I was looking for. This was an easy question indeed. Sorry...

Comment: However, what if we assumed these $f,g$ to be irreducible?